# Plot Set of Integer Points Satisfying Inequality

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, loops

I want to plot the set of lattice points in the plane in a certain range satisfying a linear inequality. For example, all points (x,y) with x and y integers between 0 and 10 satisfying x + y <= 5. I have attempted to use two for loops to do this, but this has confused pgfplots:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=10]

\foreach \a in{0,...,10}{
\foreach \b in{0,...,5-\a}{

\draw (axis cs: \a,\b) circle;

}
}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpciture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `foreach` loops doesn't work in `pgfplots` (on the same way as in pure `tikz`.
- similar functionality offer command `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`, however it not enable simple nesting of those commands

So for desired image is better to stick with pure `\tikz`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
% axis
\draw[<->]   (0,10) node[below left] {$y$} |- (10,0) node[below left] {$x$};
% dots of inequality
\foreach \x [count=\xi] in {0,...,5}
\foreach \y [count=\yi from 0] in {\x,...,5}
\fill   (\x,\yi) circle[radius=2pt];

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could just `draw` a `grid` with options `line width=2pt, line cap=round, dash pattern=on 0pt off 1cm` to get integer dots. Then `clip` what you want.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,10)node[left]{$y$}--(0,0)--(10,0)node[right]{$x$};
\clip[shift={(.1,.1)}](-1,6)--(6,-1)--(-1,-1)--cycle;
\draw[line width=2pt, line cap=round, dash pattern=on 0pt off 1cm](0,0) grid (10,10);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
view={0}{90},
xmin=0, xmax=10,
ymin=0, ymax=10,
]
\addplot3[
only marks,
domain=0:10, samples=11,
domain y=0:10, samples y=11,
z filter/.expression={x+y<=5?z:nan},
] {0};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Grap with a triangular grid of dots]